# Live streaming audio

Tags: microphone, audio, mixer, mac, streaming

I'm livestreaming a seminar on Tuesday and was curious about the sound. The event has three mics that are running to a back mixer. I'll be plugging the feed directly into my computer as an external sound source. Coming from the mixer, will the sound have any issues running as an audio input into my computer?

I've hooked a shotgun mic up by plugging the it directly into the computer and the sound on it worked well.

Comment: Which software are you using to Livestream? Your best best is to use a digital audio interface to accept a line-level auido signal from the mixing console. Most likely the mixer will not be able to deliver a mic level output signal and your laptop may have trouble dealing with that.

Answer (score 1):

When you plug a mic into your soundcard, it's typically plugged into a dedicated microphone input.

If you're going to connect the stereo output of your mixing desk to your computer, you'll most likely be using a different input, typically called the line-in (most soundcards have one).

The best way to be sure is to test it out before hand, would be asking for trouble to wait until the day to try it out!